# Cannot compile and link AVR program in OS X

Tags: arduino, avr, libc, atmega, avr-gcc

I am working on a Mac with Yosemite OS X and I'm trying to compile a program in C that I could then upload onto my Arduino. I am following [a tutorial](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/programming-arduino-uno-in-pure-c/).

I tried going through and reinstalling avr-gcc, but I got the same output. I tried searching for the file `crtatmega328p.o` on my system, but it is nowhere to be found and the same goes for the directory.

```
$ avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o Program.o Program.c
$ avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p Program.o -o Program
/usr/local/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find crtatmega328p.o: No such file or directory

/usr/local/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find -latmega328p
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @Kavanai4 As far as I could find there is no way to program in pure C using the Arduino IDE

Comment: @Kavanai4 At the moment I only have the Arduino but I eventually want to move onto programming AVR micro controllers in the raw where Arduino IDE would be of no help. Before I spend the money on new hardware I want to make sure I can do it on the Arduino first, since I already own one.

Comment: Where did you get avr-gcc from?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I compiled it from the source using [this tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-mac.html)

Comment: You did step 4 as well, correct? Which version did you install?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Yes, and I went through painstaking lengths to make sure every package was up to date, so avr-libc 1.8.1

Comment: I understand that this is not a solution, but I'm going to suggest regressing to 4.9.x for the time being. 5.2.0 seems to be looking for object files that avr-libc doesn't provide, at least not with the filename given.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I installed avr-gcc-4.9.0 and the error went away. I was able to link the program, create a hex file, flash it and now the LED light is blinking!  Please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

I was just hit by this issue on GNU/Linux last week.

Actually, the compiler works fine. The cause of the issue is a failed linking attempt against `avr-libc`.

`avr-libc-1.8.1` is simply too old to work with GCC 5. Although `1.8.1` is the latest version of `avr-libc`, but it was released one year ago... The developing version of `avr-libc` has updated to catch up GCC 5, you could clone the subversion repository:

```
svn co svn://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/avr-libc/trunk
```

and compile it by yourself. If you are not familiar about how to compile yourself home-made toolchains from the source code, there are plenty of documentation and tutorial on the web.